# Archipack window not showing anything

Tags: add-on, archipack-add-on

I haven't tried Archipack previously but anyways, after going like this:
[image]

and when I click on Windows it shows up this black patch in middle of the viewport:
[image]

I tried Wall and it worked well as it added a wall type mesh, but in this case windows aren't showing up, that black patch covers my viewport..

Comment: In some blender version, like 2.8.2, i need restart application again after render thumbs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Blender's official Archipack addon require additional setup steps in order to work.
*Preferences -> Add-ons -> archipack -> Setup Actions -> Render Thumbs*

From: 
https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/issues/88

Answer (score 3):

I confirm the new version of Archipack for Blender 2.8+ needs to run the setup option "Render preset thumbs" in order to show in the tool window on the 3D view.
It will open a terminal window (on Windows 7) showing the process. Wait for the messages to finish coming and it sould be ready to use.
[image: Process]

[image: Result]

Comment: Download material library from archipack's guthub repo before rendering thumbs so they will get materials assigned both in thumbnails images and at create time.
https://github.com/s-leger/archipack/wiki/Materials