# Blender 2.8: How can I get to the Add Objects panel from ArchiPack?

Tags: interface, add-on, archipack-add-on

I found a screenshot showing it, but I'm not sure how to bring it up.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You might need to activate the addon ArchiPack, otherwise include which other Addon you are using in your Question.
This Question looks like a duplicate to me, see:

[Archipack window not showing anything](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130584/archipack-window-not-showing-anything)

Comment: The add-on has been activated. The questions may appear similar, but it is, in fact, not a duplicate. That question is about a black patch showing up in the viewport, and mine does not involve that but a related submenu. but I received a better answer on Twitter. The secret is clicking this tab: https://i.imgur.com/LDxXhtn.png and then going down to create https://i.imgur.com/ei4S1WY.png

Answer (score 0):

Click this tab:

[image: i.imgur.com/LDxXhtn.png]

and then going down to create

[image: create tab]

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Without enabling the addon you will never get such menu.